# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError running TestNG Test in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, testng-eclipse

I am getting the Exception

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite arquillianBeforeSuite 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Endpoint.builder()Lorg/jboss/remoting3/EndpointBuilder;
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:117)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:59)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:147)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:122)
```

Running Arquillian Tests in Eclipse Oxygen with TestNG and wildfly11.
My Maven configuration is as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution was:

> remove the the Wildfly 11 Runtime
>   from the Classpath.

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Libraries (Tab)
5. remove Wildfly 11 Runtime (or Wildfly 10 Runtime)

Why is this necessary? Comments welcome...

Answer (score 14):

I also had the same issue. I tried the below solution and it worked for me like a charm.
The Solution was:

Adding the TestNG Library into the project.
Steps are:

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Libraries (Tab)
5. Go to "Add Library" and click the button.
6. Add the 'TestNG' Library and click Ok/Next.
7. TestNG Library will be added to your project.

Try Running again, it will work.

Note: I was using Java1.8 Library (had to update it from java1.5 as my eclipse create the project with default 1.5).

Answer (score 5):

Even I have faced the same issue when I was about to use the latest version of TestNG, but downgrading to a lower version of TestNG resolved the problem.

Comment: Downgrading the testNg version has also helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I also faced a similar issue when I added `TestNg` dependency version **7.8.0** in `pom.xml`.
I changed the dependency to **7.7.1** and it started working.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding testng library to the project worked for me!

Comment: Please give some examples if possible. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a maven project, upgrade your testng version to 7.1.0
and its scope to test.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse and check the testng version in installed section, just copy the same version in pom.xml
or upgrade the version of testng in eclipse